# Deploying Microsoft SQL Compact Edition to Non-English Windows XP machines.

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I have an app that uses Microsoft SQL Compact Edition.  I have followed the MSDN and deployed the DLLs described in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28VS.80%29.aspx

Including these DLLs with the installer has worked great ... until now.

Now I am trying to install the app on Non-English versions of windows.  Non-English Windows 7 works fine, but with Non-English Windows XP SP3 (Portuguese specifically) I get a crash whenever the app attempts to connect to a database.

The error is:

> Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': Falha na inicialização do aplicativo devido a configuração incorreta. A reinstalação do aplicativo pode resolver o problema. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

... yes its in Portuguese.  Google Translates it as:

> Application initialization failed due to misconfiguration. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem

If you take the other approach recommended on the MSDN page and manually install the Portuguese version of SQL Compact Edition.  Everything works fine again.  However, this is a solution I want to avoid, because this would mean distributing a SQL CE installer for every language with our installer, or a having a different installer for every language.  A huge pain.

Is there some other DLLs I could copy for international Windows versions?  Any idea where I could find this list of DLLs?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Long story short, through reverse engineering the SQL CE installer, I have found out that the SQL 3.5 CE DLLs I normally include in the installer require Visual C++ 2005, and the Portuguese Windows XP SP3 does not include it.  Specifically MSVCR80.DLL (Maybe others as well)  However just copping the DLL (and other DLLs in the folder with MSVCR80.DLL) to in the install directory with the application does not fix the problem.  Only running the install from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387 fixes the problem.  Which still leaves me with the original problem.

Comment: As you can see here, .NET 3.5 SP1 includes the required Visual C++ runtime files, don't know if that helps... http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2010/11/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ErikEJ, your suggestion made me realize our mistake.

We install and use .Net Framework 4.0, but for whatever reason we have stuck with SQL CE 3.5, and by chance it has worked since most PCs have Visual C++ Runtime 2005 pre-installed.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. Use MS SQL CE 4.0 because it depends on Visual C++ Runtime 2008, which is included in the .Net Framework 4.0 that we already install as a pre-req.
2. Find the DLLs used by SQL CE 3.5 and have our installer copy them itself (Might not be possible)
3. Install Visual C++ Runtime 2005 along with the installer.  (Not a very good installer and doesn’t have all languages)
4. Install .Net 3.5 along with 4.0, because it has Visual C++ Runtime 2005 (Better installer)

Option 1 is probably the best, but will require some work on our part, to move from 3.5 to 4.0.
All other options are work arounds, but should fix the problem.

Comment: I went with option 1, which wasn't that painful, and now the installation works on all PCs I have tested, including Portuguese ones.